# undefined methodのエラーの直し方がわかりません。

Tags: ruby

Ruby初心者です

http://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/255/1255878/
のサイトを参考に
下記のコードを作成しました。
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

```
require "minruby"
def evaluate(tree)
  case tree[0]
  when "lit"
    tree[1]
  when "+"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left + right
  when "-"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left - right
  when "*"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left * right
  else
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left / right
  end
end
str = gets
tree = minruby_parse(str)
answer = evaluate(tree)
```

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
実行結果としては

```
ex013.rb:3:in `evaluate': undefined method `  case' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

ということでした。

３行目にある、case文がメソッドとして見つからないという意味だと思うのですが、解決することができません。

ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

インデントに使われている空白が普通の空白ではなく、EN SPACE と呼ばれる別種の空白になっているようです。
以下のように普通の空白に置き換えると解決します。

```
require "minruby"
def evaluate(tree)
  case tree[0]
  when "lit"
    tree[1]
  when "+"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left + right
  when "-"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left - right
  when "*"
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left * right
  else
    left  = evaluate(tree[1])
    right = evaluate(tree[2])
    left / right
  end
end
str = gets
tree = minruby_parse(str)
answer = evaluate(tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ex013.rb:3:in `evaluate': undefined method `  case' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

をよく見てみると case の囲みの所に不自然な空白がありますね。
普通は `'単語'` のように囲まれるはずです。 `'　単語'` となっているので、ここに全角スペースがあるのかと思います。

全角スペースは見た目ではわからないため、エディターで半角スペースと見分けがつくような設定をお勧めします。